# Hide tooltip in leaflet for a zoom range

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I may have a lot of marker in some area but this is not really useful to display the tooltip if there is 5 of them in the same area, like this screen :

[image]

Is it possible to `hide` those tooltip from a zoom range ? For example, hide tooltip from the level 0 to 5.

Maybe using the `getZoom()` method with an event on the zoom like :

```
if the user zoom {
    if (getZoom() < 5) {
      hide all tooltip
    }
}
```

Or something more complicated but better which could hide it if there is too many marker in the same area ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hide tooltips based on zoom range, see this [Leaflet issue conversation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5032) that references [this JS bin](http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/sere/edit?html,output).  Code repeated below:

```
var lastZoom;
map.on('zoomend', function() {
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  if (zoom < 15 && (!lastZoom || lastZoom >= 15)) {
    map.eachLayer(function(l) {
      if (l.getTooltip) {
        var toolTip = l.getTooltip();
        if (toolTip) {
          this.map.closeTooltip(toolTip);
        }
      }
    });
  } else if (zoom >= 15 && (!lastZoom || lastZoom < 15)) {
    map.eachLayer(function(l) {
      if (l.getTooltip) {
        var toolTip = l.getTooltip();
        if (toolTip) {
          this.map.addLayer(toolTip);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  lastZoom = zoom;
})
```

**Edit:** also, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27820338/2441511).

Comment: Thanks a lot this is perfect, sorry for not having found it before !

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer did not work for me (I'm using Leaflet 1.2.0), but here is a modified version that uses the `permanent` option of Leaflet's tool tip:

```
var lastZoom;
mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
    var zoom = mymap.getZoom();
    if (zoom < tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom >= tooltipThreshold)) {
        mymap.eachLayer(function(l) {
            if (l.getTooltip()) {
                var tooltip = l.getTooltip();
                l.unbindTooltip().bindTooltip(tooltip, {
                    permanent: false
                })
            }
        })
    } else if (zoom >= tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom < tooltipThreshold)) {
        mymap.eachLayer(function(l) {
            if (l.getTooltip()) {
                var tooltip = l.getTooltip();
                l.unbindTooltip().bindTooltip(tooltip, {
                    permanent: true
                })
            }
        });
    }
    lastZoom = zoom;
})
```

Using this method you also have to set the `permanent` option when you initially bind the tool tip to the marker as well:

```
(mymap.getZoom() >= tooltipThreshold
    ? marker.bindTooltip(tooltipText, {permanent:true})
    : marker.bindTooltip(tooltipText, {permanent:false} )
);
```

On a separate but related note, the link in the accepted answer is for a stackoverflow question about the Leaflet Label plugin, which has been incorporated into the Leaflet core as the tool tip and is now obsolete, so don't waste time there if you have the latest version of Leaflet.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this in my project and ended up using something in the lines of this:

```
var tooltipThreshold = 12;
mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
  if (mymap.getZoom() < tooltipThreshold) {
      $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","none")
  } else { 
      $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","block")
  }
})
```

Or with lastZoom:

```
var lastZoom;
var tooltipThreshold = 12;
mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
    var zoom = mymap.getZoom();
    if (zoom < tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom >= tooltipThreshold)) {
        $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","none")
    } else if (zoom >= tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom < tooltipThreshold)) { 
        $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","block")
    }
    lastZoom = zoom;
})
```

Based on `Loren Maxwell` answer.

---

To disable leaflet tooltip from beginning (if you want to initiate map without tooltip), add this to css:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the visibility to achieve the same result. I think the .leaflet-tooltip class is universal for all leaflet apps.

```
//Hide tooltips based on zoom level. Currently This is set to 17
map.on('zoomend', function(e){
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel < 17 ){
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-tooltip'), function (el) {
            el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        });
    }else{
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-tooltip'), function (el) {
            el.style.visibility = 'visible';
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/show labels using the default behavior of leaflet if the zoom is out of a specific range and otherwise shows all labels, is a good idea (I think so) to make this change to the `hideLabel` function of label.js file.

```
var hideLabel = function(label) {
    label.labelObject.style.opacity = 1;
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom >= 10 ) {
        label.labelObject.style.opacity = 1;
    } else if (zoom < 10) {
        label.labelObject.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    lastZoom = zoom;
    label.labelObject.style.transition = 'opacity 0s';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but after working with Leaflet v1.6.0 I came up with a modified version:

```
var lastZoom;
var tooltipThreshold = 12;
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom >= tooltipThreshold)) {
        map.getPane('tooltipPane').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (zoom >= tooltipThreshold && (!lastZoom || lastZoom < tooltipThreshold)) { 
        map.getPane('tooltipPane').style.display = 'block';
    }
    lastZoom = zoom;
})
```

To hide tooltips for the first time, you can use **map.setView()**, **map.setZoom()** to set the zoom or use:

`map.getPane('tooltipPane').style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 0):

I like and used [Anton vBR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135663/1871068) however, for me, I used the 'moveend' map event because apparently my markerclusters prevented the tooltip from being displayed when the cluster is clicked.